# Mac aleart pop ups in openCV

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

im trying to get mac pop ups working for my little openCV project using applescript but I can't seem to get it working, I have commented out how it is meant to be done in windows but keep getting an invalid syntax error for my return value applescript

```
    __author__ = 'x'
# Required for tkinter module graphics including GUI
from tkinter import *
# ttk is a sub-module of tkinter providing more 'themed' widgets - can be mixed with  tkinter widgets
from tkinter import ttk
# Import OpenCV "Open Source Computer Vision"
import subprocess
# import subprocess for Mac alert pop up windows


    # This is a simulation of workflow execution 
    @docStringDecorator
    def executeXML_Workflow(self):
        ''' ctypes is a Python library that includes message boxes ... solution from ...
        http://win32com.goermezer.de/content/view/288/243/ '''
        import ctypes
        # Declare a messagebox
        # msgbox = ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW
        msgbox = applescript
        # Declare and initialise a counter
        count = 0
        # Declare and initialise variable to detect messagebox button press types thereby break if 2 (Quit) clicked
        returnValue = 0

        # Iterate over XML tree object and output to message box
        # NOTE: regarding Iterator Patterns, Python has built in iterators to all collections using for-in
        for wfStep in self.root.findall('wfStep'):
            # Increment the counter of workflow steps
            count += 1
            # .get is used to obtain attributes
            self.type = wfStep.get('type')
            self.API_call= wfStep.find('API_call').text
            print("self.API_call is .....................", self.API_call)

            self.name = "Step Number ... "+str(count)+"\n\nName: "+ wfStep.find('name').text+ "\n\nDescription: "+wfStep.find('description').text+"\n\nParameters: "+wfStep.find('parameters').text+ "\n\nAPI INSTRUCTION: "+wfStep.find('API_call').text
            #Create a strategy selection object delegate resolving step functions to this
            wfs = WfStepStrategyContext.BuildWfObject(self.type)
            wfs.processActions(self.API_call)
            #returnValue = msgbox(None, self.name, self.type, 1)

            returnValue = applescript """
            display dialog"""+(None,self.name,self.type, 1)"""
            with title "this is a mac pop up""
            with icon caution 
            buttons  {"OK"}
            """

            print("Return Value is ...", returnValue)
            if returnValue ==
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax error where you are defining `returnValue`.

Your code:

```
returnValue = applescript """
    display dialog"""+(None,self.name,self.type, 1)"""
    with title "this is a mac pop up""
    with icon caution 
    buttons  {"OK"}
    """
```

It is missing some concatenation which is causing your syntax error. It should instead be something like:

```
returnValue = applescript + """
    display dialog"""+(None,self.name,self.type, 1)+"""
    with title "this is a mac pop up""
    with icon caution 
    buttons  {"OK"}
    """
```

Also, this syntax with the brackets is causing more errors. Im not sure what the intention of these are exactly but I assume its for injecting variables in to the string in which case your final code would look similar to this:

```
returnValue = applescript + """
    display dialog "%s %s"
    with title "%s %s"
    with icon caution 
    buttons  {"OK"}
    """ % (None,self.name,self.type, 1)
```

You'll need to decide where the variables would go and how they would need to be formatted to display to your needs, but that should at least get you on your way.